# Using the instanceof operator to cast a parameter into a different class

Tags: java

```
public void addAnimal (Animal ananimal)
{
    listOfAnimals.add(new Animal (ananimal));
}
```

Animal is an abstract class and has LandAnimal and WaterAnimal which both extend (inherit) Animal. listOfAnimals is an ArrayList of type Animal.

How can I use the `instanceOf` operator to cast the Animal parameter to either LandAnimal or WaterAnimal so that the method addAnimal adds a copy of the Animal parameter to the ArrayList?

Comment: Why do you *think* that you need to do this? You don't.

Comment: Just `listOfAnimals.add(ananimal);` Do you have a copy constructor? If so, I guess it's fine. Just ugly. Why do you need one?

Comment: Because I want to learn.

Comment: But you're learning wrong concepts. There's no need to do this, and what's more good reason *not* to do this.

Comment: This is the way my instructor wants it done and to the person asking, yes I do have a copy constructor for all the appropriate classes

Comment: You can just do `listOfAnimals.add(ananimal)`  No need for constructing a new instance.

Comment: I will look more into this, I appreciate everyone’s suggestions.

Comment: "This is the way my instructor wants it done" - I seriously doubt that.  IMO, it is more likely that you have either misunderstood what the instructor has said, or you are not conveying it accurately to us.   Advice: ask your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
similar to the answer above, I ended up using if statements.

if(anAnimal instanceof LandAnimal)
{
    LandAnimal animal1 = (LandAnimal) anAnimal;
    listOfAnimals.add(animal1);
}

The main reason I asked was because i kept getting an error hint that LandAnimal could not be converted from boolean.
```